# install tensorflow in r and run it in python

Tags: python, r, tensorflow

I'm wondering if there is a way to install tensorflow in R and then run this installation in python. I can install tensorflow in R successfully using the instructions [here](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/). I also run the tests at that link and it is working properly.
But when I open Python and run `import tensorflow`, I get the error: `ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'`. Is here a way to make Python recognize the installation from R? Or is the only way to run tensorflow from Python to install it following the directions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/)?
The reason I want to do this is that my colleagues and I work on machines for which we do not have administrative access, and I'm trying to produce code that will work for everyone. I appreciate any advice that you might have.

Comment: You can try call Python from R "system('python test.py hello world', wait = FALSE)"

Answer (score 0):

When you load `tensorflow` or anything else running on `reticulate`, a Python environment is created (or just specified), either by the user or the the package's default. If I remember correctly, the default for tensorflow is just `r-tensorflow`.

```r
library(tensorflow)

# check with this, I used a different env name,
use_condaenv("r-tensorflow", required = TRUE)
#> Error in use_condaenv("r-tensorflow", required = TRUE): Unable to locate conda environment 'r-tensorflow'.

# If that's not it, you can check what environments are available
reticulate::conda_list()$name
#> [1] "ANACON~1"       "lime"           "r-planet"       "r-reticulate"  
#> [5] "r-tfgpu"        "spacy_condaenv"
```

Once you know which Python environment you installed it in, activate that environment to use it directly from Python... ex: run `activate r-tensorflow` from the Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still not getting this to run properly. `r-tensorflow` is the correct environment, but when I run `activate r-tensorflow` in the Anaconda Prompt, I get this error after trying to run `import tensorflow` in Python: `ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit`